# AWS Beanstalk - how to upload sitemap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My website deployed on AWS Beanstalk. Since my content is dynamic, once a day I regenerate a sitemap, which has to be deployed on my website (it has to be located under the same domain).

Previously (on Azure and shared hosting) I was doing that by uploading my sitemap files using FTP.

How I can upload sitemap on AWS Beanstalk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on @MattHouser's answer a bit, here's how I have solved this problem.

1) In your `robots.txt` file, tell crawlers where to find the sitemap:

```
Sitemap: https://www.example.com/sitemap.xml.gz
```

2) In your webserver config, redirect requests to `sitemap.xml.gz` to S3. Here's how I do it in Rails:

**config/routes.rb**

```
# Redirect sitemap files to S3 since google wants sitemaps to be hosted on the primary domain
match '/sitemap.xml.gz' =>
redirect { |params, _req|
  "https://s3.amazonaws.com/elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-xxxxxxxxxxxx/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz"
}, via: [:get]
```

Comment: Is redirect approach works with Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but I've had no issues with GWT and remotely-hosted sitemaps.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

**Option 1:**

Have the sitemap generated dynamically on request. As a possible second step, store the generated sitemap in a cache somewhere (ElastiCache, S3, etc.).

**Option 2:**

Store the sitemap on S3. When the sitemap URL is requested, download the data from S3 and forward it on to your user. When you need to update the sitemap, upload your updated data to S3.